# Apple push notification service - no notification on device

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

This problem is driving me crazy. I'm implementing APNS. I already google and followed several tutorials. I implemented the server an it seems to work find here is the code:

```
<?php

$deviceToken = 'XXXX';
// Passphrase for the private key (ck.pem file)
// $pass = '';
// Get the parameters from http get or from command line
$message = $_GET['message'] or $message = $argv[1] or $message = 'Message received from javacom';
$badge = (int)$_GET['badge'] or $badge = (int)$argv[2];
$sound = $_GET['sound'] or $sound = $argv[3];

// Construct the notification payload
$body = array();
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);
if ($badge)
    $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;

if ($sound)
    $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;

/* End of Configurable Items */

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
// assume the private key passphase was removed.
//stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx); // for production change the server to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:219
if (!$fp) {
    print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
    return;
} else {
    print "Connection OK\n";
}

$payload = json_encode($body);
$msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
print "sending message :" . $payload . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

It seems to work fine. I don't get any errors. But I don't get any push notification on my device. I don't know where the error could be. I also implemented the feedback script. No error and no output. My App is also prepared.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Apple *just* released a technical note titled ["Troubleshooting Push Notifications"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html). It has tips for both sending and receiving. Maybe something there can help.

Comment: Thanks that helped me to find the Problem